# Windows10でVSCodeからWSLに接続する際に、リモート拡張ホスト サーバーへの接続に失敗しました (エラー: WebSocket close with status code 1006)

Tags: docker, wsl

**環境**
windows10home
WSL: Ubuntu-20.04
VSCode: 1.59.1

**目標**
Windows10でVSCodeからWSLに接続していろいろしようとしています。
しかし、一度PCを再起動したりシャットダウンをすると、
vscodeを開き、WSLとリモート接続をしたときに下記のエラーが起きてしまいます。

**リモート環境をフェッチできませんでした

リモート拡張ホスト サーバーへの接続に失敗しました (エラー: WebSocket close with status code 1006)**

以前に開いたときは何とか直ったんですが、またなってしまいました。
何かやり忘れていることがあるのでしょうか？
これから先も直してもなるとすると非常に困るので、解決方法を教えてほしいです。

**試してみたこと**
以下のリンクに同じことが書いてあったので試してみました。
https://qiita.com/tatsunari/items/8fdc4022e06b54e172f9

Windowsのサービス一覧からLxssManagerを再起動　をしたら前直った気がします。
(本当にそれのおかげかはわからない。）

いずれにしても毎度エラーが起きることがないようにしたいです。

**エラー内容**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Ubuntuのコンソールでcode . するのではだめですか？